# How to create a point cloud for stereovision using python 3+?

Tags: python, opencv, point-clouds, stereo-3d

I am new to Stereo Vision, and I am trying to get **the size of an object**(length breadth, and height). I got a fine result on DepthMap. But I am not able to get any resource on how to plot a point cloud using Stereo Vision.
I am currently using OpenCV 4.2 and python 3.8

If anyone could help me with how to create a point cloud(PLY) file using python and also how to get the length, breadth, and height, please let me know.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @KlausD. Sorry for the late reply. As of now, I have a depth map and the Disparity Map. but my disparity Map is not coming clear. and I also have an issue with the depth map, it fluctuates a lot. how to make it stable?

Comment: The code, show us the code!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the open3d librady. You should export the XYZ point , it can be with reprojectImageTo3D and import to open3d. Its easily..

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).